# Change existing column to be a foreign key in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have two tables:

**events**

```
id   title                             org        date_time
---  --------------------------------  ---  -----------------------
221   UFC 226: McGregor vs. Holloway   UFC   2021-07-30 08:30:00-04
```

**matches**

```
id  event_id  fighter_a_id  fighter_b_id
--- --------  ------------  ------------
372   221          40            28
373   221          56            75
374   221         120            19
```

I was attempting to write a JOIN query, and realized that I somehow created the `event_id` column in `matches` as a VARCHAR, instead of creating it as integer foreign key. Executing a query like:

`SELECT * FROM matches JOIN events ON events.id = matches.event_id;`

does not work because it gives me a *operator does not exist: integer = character varying* error. **Is there an easy way to change `event_id` over to be a foreign key**?

Comment: If it is an integer: change/convert it to integer. (and after that, you *may* be able to put a FK constraint on it)

Comment: event_id in the matches table is a VARCHAR, not an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\i tmp.sql

-- Create some data to test it on
CREATE TABLE events (id integer PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO events(id) VALUES(221), (222);

CREATE TABLE matches
        ( id text
        ,  event_id text
        ,  fighter_a_id text
        ,  fighter_b_id text
        );
INSERT INTO matches(id, event_id,fighter_a_id,fighter_b_id) VALUES
 ('372', '221', '40', '28' )
, ('373', '221', '56', '75' )
, ('374', '221', '120', '19' )
        ;

-- Now: change the type
ALTER TABLE matches
        ALTER COLUMN event_id TYPE INTEGER USING event_id::integer
        ;

--  Now, you can add the FK-constraint on it;

ALTER TABLE matches
        ADD constraint event_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (event_id) references events(id)
        ;

\d+ matches
```

---

This wil only work if **all** the event_ids can be converted to int.

And, for non-trivial tables, you'll also need an index on the FK. This index will help if the `events` table is inserted/updated, and the constraint needs to be checked.

(this index is **not** created automatically!):

---

```
-- add a supporting index for the FK
CREATE INDEX ON matches(event_id)
        ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I'm tied up at the moment, but can give this a shot in a bit. What's the `\d+ matches` part of the query? Is that required?

Comment: No that is a `psql` meta-command (in this case: show the current table definition, including constraints and indices)

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd use this, due to the fact that I have 10,700 rows in my matches table, and 1000 events in the events table. I can't just hardcode values into my query.

Comment: You don't need to hardcode any values. All you need is table names and column names.

Comment: I was reading your snippet wrong, I didn't realize I just needed those two ALTER statements. Worked like a charm. Thank you for your help.

Comment: In regards to creating the index, should I create an index any time I create a foreign key? My matches table has two more columns that are foreign keys for another table called `fighters`. Just curious if I should be doing this all the time.

Comment: In practice: yes. `This index will help if the fighters table is inserted/updated, and the constraint needs to be checked.`

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the data as @wildplasser shows.  But for just the query, you can convert in place, using either:

```
ON events.id = matches.event_id::int
```

Or:

```
ON events.id::text = matches.event_id
```

Neither of these are really happy solutions.  The first can cause a failure if `event_id` cannot be converted to an integer.  The second can cause mismatches if `event_id` has leading `0`s.  Both can affect how the query is optimized.